# brand new L75D-A7280 battery reports 95% max when plugged in, 93% immediately after unplugged

Tags: 13.04, indicator, battery

Whenever my brand new laptop's plugged in, it reports 95% max.  It never shows 100% or charged.

Also, even though I'm not running in low power mode but am in high-GPU Catalyst mode, should it drop to to 93% immediately after unplugging?

I've looked at the bug on launchpad, and [The battery indicator& Power setting panel shows wrong battery state](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217895/the-battery-indicator-power-setting-panel-shows-wrong-battery-state), but neither help.

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try charging it all the way up ( leave it charging at least an hour after it says it is full ), run it down to 5%, then charge it all the way up again.  If the battery is still relatively healthy but aged a bit, this should trigger it to learn its correct actual capacity and may help.  Otherwise, it's probably time to replace the battery.